# Enviar mensaje desde java automáticamente?

Tags: mensajes

Estoy creando un programa en java netbeans de gestión de empleados, y necesito que el programa envié mensajes a los móviles de los empleados alguien sabe como hacerlo??

Comment: trata de documentarte por lo General seria JavaMail mira en http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html

Comment: eso seria para mandar un email, lo que necesito hacer es mandar mensajes de texto sms a movil

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que analizar los siguientes puntos:

**Via Comandos AT**

Nesecitas conserguir el hardware (Un dispositivo móvil o un módem [USB o Telefónico] que para el caso es lo mismo), y via comandos AT comunicarte con el dispositivo para enviar los mensajes o en su defecto recibirlos y leerlos.
Aquí un pedazo de mi código que hace eso:

```c#
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharp_SMS
{
  public partial class Form_SMS_Sender : Form
  {
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    public Form_SMS_Sender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string number = textBoxNumber.Text;
        string message = textBoxMessage.Text;

        //Replace "COM7"withcorresponding port name
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200);   

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Open();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r\n");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write(message + "\x1A");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        labelStatus.Text = "Status: Message sent";

        _serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que se puede rescatar es que de esta forma tu puedes personalizar tus mensajes el plan de mensajería insertarlos en bases de datos, leer mensajes recibidos hacer llamadas etc, hasta donde tu mente alcance. El contra (en mi opinión no es un contra mas bien un pro) por citar algo es que lo debes programar todo y si no tienes tiempo pues deberías escoger la otra opción.

**Usar un servicio web de mensajería**

Para este caso hay varias páginas que ofrecen este servicio
Como esta página [Link](https://www.smsperu.com/) (OJO NO ESTOY HACIENDO PUBLICIDAD NI NADA ES SOLO UN EJEMPLO) donde solo consumes un servicio web y ellos después te facturan por la cantidad de sms enviados.
El pro es que te olvidas de este módulo porque solo lo consumes.
El contra es que suelen ser algo costosos y no se envían de manera instantánea, ya que hay que esperar cierto periodo de tiempo.

Comment: Eh intentado lo de los comandos at, para verificar que funcione la conexion  utilice la hyperterminal con un modem, y en la misma pongo at para comenzar la conexion pero ahi se queda no recibo respuesta. luego e intentado con un smartphone y al tratar de enviar el mensaje tira error 500. tienes idea de que puede ser

Comment: lo tienes en tus puertos COM? osea lo detecta como un puerto COM?

Comment: si, el error aparece al enviarle los comandos

Comment: Ya, puede ser 2 cosas, el puerto com o la velocidad, hay una forma de saberlo :
vas a administrador de dispositivos > en el puerto com de tu modem usb le das click derecho y pones propiedades y luego vas a la pestaña de Configuracion de puerto, ahi vas a ver la configuracion de tu modem para q la uses en tu aplicación.

Comment: Parece estar todo correcto, sabes si hay que hacerle alguna configuración al dispositivo, ademas de ponerlo en modo módem?

Comment: Puedes utilizar un programa para manejar los puertos com. Yo utilizo el IDE de arduino solo para los comandos, y verifico ahi si otra app esta utilizando el puerto.